# @Html.CheckBoxFor( cannot work with null boolean?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

runtime error: cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to bool.  An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

sql database type = bit
MVC View controller for corresponding variable = checkbox

question:
if the sql database field type is BIT with 3 states, 
sql database type = bit  (true/false/null)

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

A checkbox only has 2 states... checked vs unchecked.  So a third state for `null` wouldn't be logical.  If you are trying to consider null as false, then do that conversion in your controller while creating your view model.

Something like `myViewModel.MyBool = dto.MyBitColumn != null && dto.MyBitColumn;`

Now you can use `myViewModel.MyBool` for your checkbox.

Comment: If a 0 of unchecked and 1 is checked, what would the null be considering a checkbox?

Comment: If you go with the plan of making everything non nullable, you are going to run into more headaches because now you have to sanitize every field.

Comment: So if you are considering null as false (not selected), why not just make it a non nullable bool, which defaults to false?  Now you do not need extra logic...  or you can still do what I offered in my answer.  I honestly think you are going to be angry at yourself when you start passing database poco's to your business logic and have to call `.value` everywhere as well as null reference checks.

Answer (score 0):

The `@CheckBoxFor()` method only work for a `boolean` property. The signature of the method is

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression)
```

Note the `TResult` in `Func` is `bool`. The reason that a checkbox has only 2 states - check or unchecked which equates to `true` or `false`.

If your property `PType1` is `bool?` (nullable), you need to use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PType1)
```

which will generate a dropdownlist with 3 values, "Not Set" (which equates to `null`), "True" and "False".

Side note: *"observation: there is no checkbox control that can be used with a corresponding sql type of bit"*. Yes there is. `@Html.CheckBox()` can be use with `bit` so long as the field is `NOT NULL` which equates to `bool`. If you only want to store `true` or `false` then set the field to be `NOT NULL`

Comment: No its not possible, and I cant imagine why you think it could be. And you cannot bind to a string using a `CheckBoxFor()` - see my answer to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901438/use-or-replace-html-checkboxfor-to-fill-in-string-variable-in-mvc). What are you really trying to do? You cant save the value "YES" to a sql bit field!

Comment: You could create your own checkbox which will be grayed out if null so it can indicate never set.  Once clicked on, it can turned un-grayed and unchecked to show the user set it explicitly to false.  Then click again to check...